# How to use PaperJs to bounce images around

Tags: javascript, html, image, animation, paperjs

The following is a PaperJS program that shows circles bouncing around: http://paperjs.org/examples/candy-crash/. The code there is a bit of an overkill by many accounts, and in fact I am not interested in the code itself; I just point to it so you can see the kind of animation I am interested in. But I don't know how to do something similar with images. Supposedly what I need to do is simple, but being new to html5 and PaperJS, I don't know how to do it. So maybe someone here can help me out. If you look at the animation I link to, it should give you an idea of what I want to accomplish. I don't care for the distortions. I just want the images to bounce against each other in a similar random fashion. Thanks for any help.

BTW: I asked a similar version of this question before doing more research here: [How to add image to Path in PaperJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27428726/how-to-add-image-to-path-in-paperjs)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add image to Path in PaperJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27428726/how-to-add-image-to-path-in-paperjs)

Answer (score -2):

For every ball, add a raster. On every frame, move the raster to where the ball is.

Comment: I think it's obvious that the question is not what but **how**. But I don't like to downvote answers. So no downvote.